# how do i fix untiy3d objects appear white at some sides

Tags: unity-game-engine, object, lighting

I installed hdrp on my project and then removed it because it broke some things and after removing it some of the objects appeared pink and after playing with it they are now half the real color half white and I don't know how to fix it.

[image: this is how it looks]

Comment: looks like a problem with your lighting/rendering which is overall way to bright/intense? Do you have white [ambient light](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-ambient-light.html)?

Comment: I need to check that... do you know where this is located?

Comment: `Ambient light settings can be found in the Lighting window.` -> [Lighting Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html)

Comment: i dont see any ambient light, only found ambient occlusion

Comment: Removing HDRP causes Texture and Materials missing, that object becomes pink you can resolve it by going in Edit -> Render PipeLine -> Upgrade it to URP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive thanks to Kellphy for helping me solve this.
It seemed like I broke something with the lights in level 1 but everything in level 2 was fine, all I had to do was copy the lights from level 2 to 1

[Level 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGHGW.png)

[Level 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRSTJ.png)

Please note that 3 years have passed and I might have forgotten if I did anything else to fix it but from what I remember this was the issue.